# Eclipse CDT 5.0.1 (Ganymede) slow indexer problem

Tags: c++, eclipse, indexing, eclipse-cdt, ganymede

I am trying to use Ganymede CDT to index our large codebase. It is painfully slow, can take a whole night to index the C++ files. Same project takes only 5 seconds to index with exuberant ctags 5.7.

Is there some way to find what the root of the problem is and to speed it up?
Maybe turn on logging in CDT, or some obscure option somewhere that I missed?

Comment: You should report this on the cdt-dev@eclipse.org mailinglist. I don't believe too many CDT developers are reading SO.

Comment: Which Indexer mode are use using (Fast or Full)?  Also, how many lines of code are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the "full indexer" this would not surprise me. I'm using the "fast indexer", it is very fast and works pretty well (even with wxWidgets).

You can change your indexer settings in Window->Preferences->C/C++->Indexer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if this is a regression from 5.0.0? In that case you should definitely open a bugreport.

Is all of your code in the same project? That may have an impact.

Comment: All of the code is in one project, and no - I did not test it with 5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar problem with Eclipse under Windows; in our case, it is because of an old version of cygwin.

To know if you have the same issue, just check with [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) if Eclipse spawns cygpath.exe, and it does not complete in a reasonable time.
In case this is the cause of the problem, then it is enough to just put the last version of cygpath.exe and cygwin1.dll in eclipse directory, and then you are done.

Good luck!